# Syntax error (python script with arcpy)

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, syntaxerror

My ArcPy script doesn't run because a syntax error was raised, but I already had checked the syntax and indentation of the entire script.

Can anyone help me?

The error that was raised points to a colon that's the end of 'if' on the line 236 as you see in the print screen below.

[image]

Comment: No it's because you're missing a closing bracket on the preceding line. `count = Int(arcpy.get... .getOutput(0) **)**` Please don't post your whole code when asking a question, it's really hard to find the line with an error; if you use a good python editor you can check for these types of syntax errors fairly quickly.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelStimson on both counts - please try to always present a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) rather than code.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! Now, how do I close or mark as answered this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unclosed parentheses just above the error line:

```
count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management('copyFC_lyr').getOutput(0)
```

Should be:

```
count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management('copyFC_lyr').getOutput(0))
```